# Representing 0 as a negative for gnss coordinates

Tags: c

I have a function that returns degrees and minutes as DDDMMMMMMM for gnss coordinates.

To extract the degrees part, i did an integer division as DDDMMMMMMM / (10^7).

But the problem is , if DDD is 0, I lose the sign.
How can I preserve the sign of DDD so that the client that uses it can know its 0 with a negative.
+0 and -0 is used to position North, South,East , West.

-0001234567 / (10^7)  -> -0 degrees

The client uses my returned value like:

If(DDD < 0) --> take it as a negative degree.
The client then uses this returned degree and plots  on the display as DDD or -DDD .

Function:

```
int16 getDegree(int32 degreeMinutes)
{
   int16 degree = (int16)(degreeMinutes/10000000); //DDDMMMMMMM/10^7 = DDD 
   return degree;
}
```

Other than using another variable to check if the number is negative like below, i dont see any other way that it can be done:

```
struct degree
{
  int16 degree;
  bool isNegative;
}degreeObj;

struct degree getDegree(int32 degreeMinutes)
{
   degreeObj.isNegative = false;
   degreeObj.degree = (int16)(degreeMinutes/10000000); //DDDMMMMMMM/10^7 
   if(degreeMinutes < 0) //DDDMMMMMMM as a whole is less than 0
   degreeObj.isNegative = true;

   return degreeObj;
}
```

The client then,will only have to check if degreeObj.isNegative is true

Comment: im just supposed to extract the DDD part and return it. The client just plots the coordinate. Another module gives it as -1801234567, i return -180

Comment: How does `-0` differ from `0`?

Comment: -0 is a valid coordinate for gnss position

Comment: Both are valid. How does it _differ_? The +0 and -0 for both longitute and latitute should give you exactly the same position, shouldn't it? Or does the +0''E differ from -0''E in location?

Comment: @KamilCuk in floating point representation. A negative value might  be closer to `0` than the next lowest representable value, and the information can be useful to, say, determine which quadrant an angle is in. Or in the case of a vector, still tells you its direction.

Comment: I don't see a way that you can do what you want with integers. Two fixes are possible: (1) Use float, where -0 can exist, but to detect it you can't just ask <0 (2) use -360, which will be technically correct, but might break other code. You might also use +360 for positive zero, and 0 for exactly 0.

Comment: Your question does not state how you communicate with the client. Are you sending the client a string containing numerals and other information? Are you sending the client numbers in `int` and `float` objects (or in bytes containing the representations of `int` and `float` objects)? Can the format used to communicate with the client be changed—can you send a `float` or `double` where you are now sending an `int`? Show some code that explains where the problem occurs.

Comment: -0 or 0 is used to find North , south , west or east

Comment: I cant use float or double

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way that you can do what you want with integers. You can't simply use the degrees part of the value as a signed zero integer.

As others have said, it is hard to understand why you would care. If you don't care that the value 09059... is closer to 091, then why do you care that -00010... is distinct from +00010... ? Perhaps what you really need to do is round the value to the nearest whole degree, then 000 degrees represents -00030 to +00030?

Three fixes are possible, though:

1) Use float to represent your integer degrees. Float does have a concept of negative zero, but you can't simply compare with < 0 to detect it;

2) Use -360, as technically equal to -0 degrees. But that might break the code you are calling. If you go down this path, you could also use +360 to represent a "positive" zero, and keep 0 just for when the value is exactly 0 to the last decimal;

3) Convert the whole DDDMMMMMM to a real (probably a double) that represents the MMMMM as a decimal. This way the sign is easily preserved.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply: You can not reliably use negative zero integers in C, since the signed integer representation could be either ones complement or twos complement.
Since twos complement has no negative zero and is the dominant and also might be the mandatory representation for future C standards, integers are simply not your choice in C.

So I recommend to be pragmatic and just floating point types, like a `double`, which should usually have enough precision for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the negative value:

```
-DDDMMMMMMM
```

It can be rewritten:

```
(-DDD) + (-MMMMMMM)
```

which can be calculated with:

```
(-DDDMMMMMMM / 10) + (-DDDMMMMMMM % 10)
```

where % is the operator for `modulo` in the C programming language.

Therefore if

```
DDD = 0
```

you will still have

```
-MMMMMMM
```

which remains negative.

Overall, you do not need to worry so much about postive zeros and negative zeros, in my opinion. The sign is still there somewhere.

---

As already pointed out, in order to have exactly what you want, you should save the sign, make the division using the absolute value of the -DDDMMMMMMM, and then apply the sign again, as needed.